# Pandas: find group index of first row matching a predicate in a group, if any

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group a DataFrame by some criteria, and then find the integer index **in the group** (*not* the DataFrame) of the first row satisfying some predicate.  If there is no such row, I want to get `NaN`.

For example, I group by column `a` divided by 5 and then in each group, find the index of the first row where column `b` is "red":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': xrange(12), 'b': ['red', 'green', 'blue'] * 4})


     a      b
0    0    red
1    1  green
2    2   blue
3    3    red
4    4  green
5    5   blue
6    6    red
7    7  green
8    8   blue
9    9    red
10  10  green
11  11   blue

df.groupby(df.a // 5).apply(lambda g: next((idx for idx, row in g.reset_index(drop=True).iterrows() if row.b == "red"), None))


a
0     0
1     1
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

(I guess I'm assuming rows stay in the same order as the in original DataFrame, but I can sort the group if needed.)  Is there a more concise, efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit longer, but IMHO is more understandable / customizable

```
In [126]: df2 = df.copy()
```

This is your group metric

```
In [127]: g = df.a//5
```

A reference to the create groups

```
In [128]: grp = df.groupby(g)
```

Create a columns of the generated group and the cumulative count within the group

```
In [129]: df2['group'] = g

In [130]: df2['count'] = grp.cumcount()

In [131]: df2
Out[131]: 
     a      b  group  count
0    0    red      0      0
1    1  green      0      1
2    2   blue      0      2
3    3    red      0      3
4    4  green      0      4
5    5   blue      1      0
6    6    red      1      1
7    7  green      1      2
8    8   blue      1      3
9    9    red      1      4
10  10  green      2      0
11  11   blue      2      1
```

Filtering and grouping gives you back the first elemnt that you want. The count is the within group count

```
In [132]: df2[df2.b=='red'].groupby('group').first()
Out[132]: 
       a    b  count
group               
0      0  red      0
1      6  red      1
```

You can generate all of the group keys (e.g. nothing came back from your filter); this way.

```
In [133]: df2[df2.b=='red'].groupby('group').first().reindex(grp.groups.keys())
Out[133]: 
    a    b  count
0   0  red      0
1   6  red      1
2 NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do:

```
import itertools as it
df.groupby(df.a // 5).apply(lambda group: next(it.chain(np.where(group.get_values() == "red")[0], [None])))
```

The only real difference is using `np.where` on the values (so I'd expect this to be faster usually), but you may even want to just write your own `first_where` function and use that.