# Multiindexed Pandas groupby, ignore a level?

Tags: python, filter, pandas

I'm running a `groupby` operation on a multiindexed DataFrame similar to this one:

```
                                        0         1    ...
categories features subfeatures                    
cat1       feature1 subfeature1 -0.224487 -0.227524
                    subfeature2 -0.591399 -0.799228
           feature2 subfeature1  1.190110 -1.365895    ...
                    subfeature2  0.720956 -1.325562
cat2       feature1 subfeature1  1.856932       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.354258 -0.740473
           feature2 subfeature1  0.234075 -1.362235    ...
                    subfeature2  0.013875  1.309564
cat3       feature1 subfeature1       NaN       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.260408  1.559721    ...
           feature2 subfeature1  0.419246  0.084386
                    subfeature2  0.969270  1.493417

...                    ...               ...
```

And it can be generated using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed=90)
results = np.random.randn(3,2,2,2)
results[2,0,0,:] = np.nan
results[1,0,0,1] = np.nan
results = results.reshape((-1,2))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"],
                                    ["feature1", "feature2"], 
                                    ["subfeature1", "subfeature2"]], 
                                   names=["categories", "features", "subfeatures"])
df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=index)
```

I am attempting to select only the groups that have a maximum difference between two subfeature arrays that is greater than a certain threshold, but I'm having trouble with `groupby`

```
df.groupby(level=['categories','features'])
```

This gives me the following groups:

```
{('cat1', 'feature1'): [('cat1', 'feature1', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat1', 'feature1', 'subfeature2')],
 ('cat1', 'feature2'): [('cat1', 'feature2', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat1', 'feature2', 'subfeature2')],
 ('cat2', 'feature1'): [('cat2', 'feature1', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat2', 'feature1', 'subfeature2')],
 ('cat2', 'feature2'): [('cat2', 'feature2', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat2', 'feature2', 'subfeature2')],
 ('cat3', 'feature1'): [('cat3', 'feature1', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat3', 'feature1', 'subfeature2')],
 ('cat3', 'feature2'): [('cat3', 'feature2', 'subfeature1'),
  ('cat3', 'feature2', 'subfeature2')]}
```

Is there any way to group so that the subfeature level is ignored by the `groupby` function? The reason is that I need both `subfeature1` and `subfeature2` together, in separate groups they're worthless.

So ideally I would want the `groupby` to return something like this:

```
{('cat1', 'feature1'): [('cat1', 'feature1')],
 ('cat1', 'feature2'): [('cat1', 'feature2')],
 ('cat2', 'feature1'): [('cat2', 'feature1')],
 ('cat2', 'feature2'): [('cat2', 'feature2')],
 ('cat3', 'feature1'): [('cat3', 'feature1')],
 ('cat3', 'feature2'): [('cat3', 'feature2')],
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: df.reset_index(level='subfeatures').groupby(level=['categories','features']).groups
Out[20]: 
{('cat1', 'feature1'): [('cat1', 'feature1'), ('cat1', 'feature1')],
 ('cat1', 'feature2'): [('cat1', 'feature2'), ('cat1', 'feature2')],
 ('cat2', 'feature1'): [('cat2', 'feature1'), ('cat2', 'feature1')],
 ('cat2', 'feature2'): [('cat2', 'feature2'), ('cat2', 'feature2')],
 ('cat3', 'feature1'): [('cat3', 'feature1'), ('cat3', 'feature1')],
 ('cat3', 'feature2'): [('cat3', 'feature2'), ('cat3', 'feature2')]}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not have the duplicates among the values? For example, `('cat1', 'feature1')` is included twice in the values list.

Comment: what are you doing with this? you almost never need to use ``.groups`` direcly. their are no dups, you have 2 rows in each group.

Comment: I'm doing comparisons between the array of numbers to the right of the subfeature column. I would like to compare the `subfeature1` array to the `subfeature2` array once per (cat, feature) group.

Comment: Basically the problem boils down to: Can you groupby with masking an index? The `subfeature` descriptor should be ignored while grouping, but is important for the filter function. The subfeatures represent a standard attribute of feature that is the same everywhere.

Comment: well you can simply access the subfeatures field in the apply then.

Comment: How would I be able to grab the row of numbers following `subfeature1`, for example? I can only think of ways to do this when `subfeature1` is an index, which it isn't anymore.

Comment: Why are row numbers useful? do the computation and return the result. Or use cumcount if you really want the numbers. maybe like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375909/pandas-find-group-index-of-first-row-matching-a-predicate-in-a-group-if-any/24376412#24376412

Comment: It's not the row numbers that are useful, but all the numbers following the `subfeature` column, i.e. the ones in column 0, 1 ... etc

Comment: well that is exactly what is passed to the applied function a sub-frame.

Comment: I figured it out. I just set `subfeatures` as an index within the filter function. Hackish, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

With Jeff's help I managed to figure a solution that works.

```
def f(x):
    tmp = x.set_index('subfeatures')
    a = (tmp.xs('subfeature1')-tmp.xs('subfeature2')).abs().max()
    return a > 1

df.reset_index('subfeatures').groupby(level=['categories', 'features']).filter(f).set_index('subfeatures', append=True)
```

I basically ignore `subfeatures` for grouping and then temporarily add it back within the filter function, but that gets lost so I finalize it after the filter function completes.