# reset_index() to original column indices after pandas groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, indices

I generate a grouped dataframe `df = df.groupby(['X','Y']).max()` which I then want to write (to csv, without indexes). So I need to convert 'X' and 'Y' back to regular columns; I tried using `reset_index()`, but the order of columns was wrong.

**How to restore columns 'X' and 'Y' to their exact original column position?**

Is the solution:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

and then find a way to change the order of the columns?

---

(I also found [this approach, for multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716324/multiindex-pandas-groupby-aggregate-keep-full-index))

Comment: Is the `FutureWarning` coming from the `lambda x: x == x.max()`? If you need it to be an identity check, presumably you can use `lambda x: x is x.max()`.

Comment: Does this work? `outputframe.groupby(['somecol','someothercol'],as_index=False).max()`

Comment: I did not understand your question at all. Do you want to remove `NaN` values from your columns by discarding the rows? Or do you want to combine the rows together into a single row?

Comment: @Kartik There are semi-duplicates in a table with incomplete rows. If two rows match in a couple specified columns, they are deemed as duplicates. I then want these two rows to be comined into a single row while retaining/merging as much information as possible. There are a lot of cases where there are additional columns in which one row has a string-value and the other one is nan and I then want the string value to be present in the merged row.

Comment: I also do not understand your question at all, and I don't see where 'somecol','someothercol' come from. Given the first part (merging multiple rows) is solved and not an issue, please remove all references to it and show us 'somecol','someothercol' on line 1. Or whatever startpoint you need to make this an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise noone else can understand or reuse this question.

Comment: Like why can't you just call `'somecol','someothercol'` `'X','Y'` instead? Heaps clearer. Also, I deleted the unnecessary preamble about where the df came from (merging incomplete/ragged rows). While you're at it, you could also rename `outputframe` to `df`. (UPDATE: I just went ahead and did it, for the sake of clarity)

Comment: **Just use `reset_index()` then reorder columns e.g. `[2,0,1]` or whatever**

Comment: So I deleted all the unnecessary discussion of the answer you linked, FutureWarning, I don't even see how you can compare non-numerics with `.transform(lambda x: x == x.max()).astype(bool)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution keeps the columns as-is and doesn't create indexes, after grouping, hence we don't need `reset_index()` and column reordering at the end:

```
df.groupby(['X','Y'],as_index=False).max()
```

(After testing a lot of different methods, the simplest one was the best solution (as always) and the one which eluded me the longest. Thanks to @maxymoo for pointing it out.)