# restore index after groupby.size() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to have index restored after `groupby.size()` or have it available but kinda it doesn't work with `.size()`. I've read the stackoverflow post [Pandas - Restore Index after Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020064/pandas-restore-index-after-groupby) but all help replies goes strictly using `max()` aggreagation function, what about others?

A little bit of code samples:

```
df
Out[39]:
      product_id
order_id    
2103    7546
2103    8278
2103    6790
2104    7546
2104    8278
2104    6790


df.groupby('product_id', as_index=True).size()
Out[67]:
product_id
3587      1
3590      1
3680      2
6735      5
6744      1
6759      6

df.groupby('product_id', as_index=False).size()
Out[68]:
product_id
3587      1
3590      1
3680      2
6735      5
6744      1
6759      6
```

As you can see after changing as_index parameter to `True` or `False` nothing happens with index. But all works with `.max()` aggr function. So, anyway the question is how to get the index restored after `groupby.size()`.

Expected output:

```
    product_id
index   
2103 3587      1
2104 3590      1
2188 3680      2
2188 6735      5
2188 6744      1
2188 6759      6
```

Comment: what you mean restore here ?

Comment: `as_index` deals with returned grouped objects labels as index, not their respective index in the df. Can you show expected output?

Comment: Do you just want to add a column with `product_id` count? In that case you can use `df['count'] = df.product_id.map(df.product_id.value_counts())` .

Comment: @Wen I mean have index "order_id" in df to be seen as an index in dataframe after groupby

Comment: For `product_id` 6790, there are two different `order_id`. Which one should be shown?

Comment: @IvanShelonik you agg with product_id, but index does not agg , so you want the first index of each group?

Comment: @Wen Maybe I somewhere copied that I did just for the example. This is the real code

df.join(df, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y') \
            .groupby(['product_id_x', 'product_id_y']).size() \
            .rename('shared_order_id') \
            .reset_index() \
            .sort_values(by=['shared_order_id'], ascending=False)

I want to have the index of order id at the end of all manilupations

Comment: @IvanShelonik Maybe you can add to the question the desired output.

Comment: @ Ami Tavory Added

Comment: `df.groupby(['order_id','product_id']).size()`

Comment: @Wen Thanks a lot. Sorry for the bad explained question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you perform a `groupby`, the original index is lost. This is because, internally, `pandas` uses the grouper column(s) as an index.

What you can do is elevate your index to a column, map counts of `product_id` via a pre-calculated series, and then set index again.

`value_counts` can be used instead of `groupby.size` for this task.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [7546, 8278, 6790, 7546, 8278, 6790]},
                  index=[2103, 2103, 2103, 2104, 2104, 2104])

c = df.product_id.value_counts()

res = df.reset_index()
res['count'] = res['product_id'].map(c)
res = res.set_index('index')

print(res)

       product_id  count
index                   
2103         7546      2
2103         8278      2
2103         6790      2
2104         7546      2
2104         8278      2
2104         6790      2
```