# How to group-by twice, preserve original columns, and plot

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following data sets (only sample is shown):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to find the most impactful exercise per area and then plot it via Seaborn barplot.
I use the following code to do so.

```
# Create Dataset Using Only Area, Exercise and Impact Level Chategories
    CA_data = Data[['area', 'exercise', 'impact level']]

    # Compute Mean Impact Level per Exercise per Area
    mean_il_CA = CA_data.groupby(['area', 'exercise'])['impact level'].mean().reset_index()

    mean_il_CA_hello = mean_il_CA.groupby('area')['impact level'].max().reset_index()

    # Plot
    cx = sns.barplot(x="impact level", y="area", data=mean_il_CA_hello)
    plt.title('Most Impactful Exercises Considering Area')
    plt.show()
```

The resulting dataset is:
[image]

This means that when I plot, on the y axis only the label relative to the area appears, NOT 'area label' + 'exercise label' like I would like.

[image]

How do I reinsert 'exercise column into my final dataset?
How do I get both the name of the area and the exercise on the y plot?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of losing the values of 'exercise' when grouping by the maximum of 'area' can be solved by keeping the MultiIndex (i.e. not using `reset_index`) and using [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to create a boolean mask to select the appropriate full rows of `mean_il_CA` that contain the maximum 'impact_level' values per 'area'. This solution is based on the code provided in [this answer by unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28717806/14148248). The full labels for the bar chart can be created by concatenating the labels of 'area' and 'exercise'.

Here is an example using the titanic dataset from the seaborn package. The variables 'class', 'embark_town', and 'fare' are used in place of 'area', 'exercise', and 'impact_level'. The categorical variables both contain three unique values: 'First', 'Second', 'Third', and 'Cherbourg', 'Queenstown', 'Southampton'.

```py
import pandas as pd    # v 1.2.5
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.1

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
data = df[['class', 'embark_town', 'fare']]
data.head()
```

[image: data_head]

```py
data_mean = data.groupby(['class', 'embark_town'])['fare'].mean()
data_mean
```

[image: data_mean]

```py
# Select max values in each class and create concatenated labels
mask_max = data_mean.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x == x.max())
data_mean_max = data_mean[mask_max].reset_index()
data_mean_max['class, embark_town'] = data_mean_max['class'].astype(str) + ', ' \
                                      + data_mean_max['embark_town']
data_mean_max
```

[image: data_mean_max]

```py
# Draw seaborn bar chart
sns.barplot(data=data_mean_max,
            x=data_mean_max['fare'],
            y=data_mean_max['class, embark_town'])
```

[image: sns_barplot]